# Acessing another structure's member through a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct node
    {
        int data;
        struct node *next;

    };

    struct node n1,n2,n3;
    int i;
    n1.data = 100;
    n2.data = 200;
    n3.data = 300;

    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.next = &n3;

    i = n1.(*next).data;
    printf("%i\n",i);

    printf("%i\n", n2.next->data);

    return 0;
}
```

My Question is simple. How come i am not able to access n2 node via n1 node when i use this `i = n1.(*next).data;` I get an error. However if i change it to `i=n1.next->data`

I thought `(*x).y` and `x->y` mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, `(*x).y` and `x->y` mean the same thing, that's why you should write [`(*n1.next).data`](http://ideone.com/qq3Gu5) (equivalent to `n1.next->data` as `n1.next` is your `x`).

**EDIT:** The parenthesis are so due to the evaluation order:

1. Take n1: `n1` (a `struct node`)
2. Take member next: `(n1).next` (a `struct node *`)
3. Deference the pointer: `*((n1).next)` (a `struct node`)
4. Take member data: `(*((n1).next)).data` (an `int`)

Read what the C11 standard says in the @Christophe answer, and notice how the `.` operator used in steps 2 and 4 above where used with `struct node` as first operands (see steps 1 and 3) and member names as seconds operands.

Comment: how come n1 is inside parentheses?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax requires `i = (*n1.next).data`;

Why ?

- C11 standard says "*The first operand of the . operator shall have an atomic, qualified, or unqualified structure or union type, and the second operand shall name a member of that type.*" (§ 6.5.2.3). So  `n1.*next`and `n1.*(next)`are not legal, because operator `.` can  be followed only by a member **name**.
- `n1.next` is of type "pointer to struct node", you may dereference it with operator `*` or `->`.
- Through dereferencing, `*n1.next` would be a value of type "struct node".  Unfortunately, the prefix operator `*` has a [lower precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than `.`.  This is why `*n1.next.data` would mean `*(n1.next.data)` which is of course invalid because `n1.next` is a pointer, and pointer do not by themselves have members.   But `(*n1.next)` is of type "struct node", so `(*n1.next).data`correctly refers to the member's value.
- This kind of derefenrcing is quite common, so there is  `->`.  The standard says "*The first operand of the -> operator shall have type ‘‘pointer to atomic, qualified, or unqualified structure’’ (...) and the second operand shall name a member of the type pointed to.*".  This explains the `n1.next->data`.  Fortunately the precedence of `.` and `->` are the same and they evaluate from left to the right, so no parentheses required.